# Adding functionality to existing (closed-source) applications on Android

Tags: android, dalvik

I want to add some functionality to existing (closed-source) applications on Android. For example: adding an item in the context-menu.

Is this possible? My guess is to hack my way into the Dalvik VM, but I can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Generally, no. If the "existing (closed-source) applications" have an API that they publish and document, you are welcome to use such an API. Or, if the "existing (closed-source) applications" are leveraging so-called implicit `Intent` actions, like `ACTION_SEND`, you can simply support those interfaces.

For example, many applications have some sort of "share" menu item or button, which brings up a list of applications capable of sharing the content the original app wishes to share. This is accomplished via `ACTION_SEND`, and if you create an activity set up to respond properly to `ACTION_SEND` requests, your activity can appear in this list automatically, no hacking required.

> My guess is to hack my way into the Dalvik VM

Fortunately, that will not work. You cannot "hack [your] way into the Dalvik VM" running in another process.

Comment: agreed, as the code is obfuscated - depending how the original code has been obfuscated (as ProGuard has many different option).

Comment: "Fortunately, that will not work. You cannot "hack [your] way into the Dalvik VM" running in another process". If you are implying that one is restricted from operations on a process (and associated memory space) you don't have ownership of, it would be worth mentioning that DLL injection can overcome this hurdle without much effort.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I can say that you can. You should find the application, disassemble (dedex) it, make changes and build it once again. You can look at the different tutorials how do this.

Comment: agreed, for example, the famous malware "DroidDream" has been reversed engineered by many people, and it is possible to reproduce an almost identical replica or the original code.   but if the obfuscation goes far enough, then reversing will definitely be difficult.   Looking into the code generated by the dedexing, you will only see lots of numbers - as exemplified by DroidDream itself.